# How to for loop in print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to format my output to print with 7 whitespaces at the beginning.

```
for i in range(1,17):
    print(i, end=' ')
```

How could I include that in a formatted statement? 
For example:

```
print("{0:>7}".format(for loop to print horizontal line of numbers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want exactly 7 spaces (not a total width of 7 characters, including the value), you probably want to manually add `"       "` or `" " * 7`. How about:

```
print(" "*7 + " ".join(str(i) for i in range(1, 17)))
```

Output:

```
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

If you need special formatting for the individual numbers (such as padding them to a common width), just make a `format` call instead of `str`:

```
print(" "*7 + " ".join(format(i, "2d") for i in range(1, 17)))
```

Output:

```
        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
#      ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^ note extra spaces padding the 1-digit numbers to width 2
```

Comment: Thanks,this is just what I was looking for! I don't fully understand how I could make that a formatted statement where I could add to the end or beginning of the number sequence. Please elaborate on making a "format call instead of str." Should I take the entire statement minus the "print" and put it as an argument in a formatted print statment?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show what I was referring to there. I'm not sure if it's something you actually need or not, but if you're trying to do nicely formatted output, it might be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. And one last clarification: say I want to prepend or append the number sequence with something. Can that work as it seems the 'format' function is nested in join?

Comment: sorry, hit return before I was done. Example: "** This is a sequence 1,2,3,4,5 * is the sequence."

Comment: You can either do that with list concatenation (using `+`, as I do with the spaces in my answer), or wrap the `join` call in another format operation. So, for the example in your comment, you'd want something like `print("** This is a sequence {} * is the sequence.".format(",".join(str(i) for i in range(1, 6))))`

Comment: You are the man! (I took the liberty of assuming you're a man from your usrname... :)  Obviously, I'm new here, it seems I cannot give you more credit than "correct answer."" Pls advise if wrong.